# I want to make a Url as simple and short

Tags: javascript, c#, azure

I am using MVC .I want to hide or format the url query string (like this http://some.in/category/news-and-events/page/29/) in my project iam passing some datas through `@Html.ActionLink` but Url appears as a `News-Events?newsEvents=3&pageNumber=28` .So i want it to be  with the format or hide.
This is the code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Older Posts","News-Events", "SITI", new { newsEvents = ViewBag.Title.Id, pageNumber = @ViewBag.PageNumber + 1 })
```

This is the startup.cs file containing code..If i remove id i cant send data through url

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

Comment: Your example url does not conatin a value for the `newsEvents`-id

Comment: @Ackdari through ViewBag values for both newsEvents and pageNumber come

Comment: I guess if you would use default values in your routing for the parameters, you could remove the `&pageNumber=28` and replace it with `/28`. But it will depends on the other parameters you have.

Comment: @Vestel I have added startup.cs in my  question please tell me what i have to change ,that will not effect other routers in project .Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will depends on the framework you are using. But you should be able to find your route config file. If you open that, you could add a new route or modify the existing one with your default parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{pageNumber}",
    defaults: new { controller = "SITI", action = "News-Events", pageNumber = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then you'll be able to put the pagenumber in the url without the prefix `pageNumber=X`. But you'll still need to add a parameter for your newsEvents